# How can I redirect the logger to a wxPython textCtrl using a custom logging handler?

Tags: python, logging, wxpython

I'm using a module in my python app that writes a lot a of messages using the logging module. Initially I was using this in a console application and it was pretty easy to get the logging output to display on the console using a console handler. Now I've developed a GUI version of my app using wxPython and I'd like to display all the logging output to a custom control — a multi-line textCtrl. Is there a way i could create a custom logging handler so i can redirect all the logging output there and display the logging messages wherever/however I want — in this case, a wxPython app.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Create Handler

```
import wx
import wx.lib.newevent

import logging

# create event type
wxLogEvent, EVT_WX_LOG_EVENT = wx.lib.newevent.NewEvent()


class wxLogHandler(logging.Handler):
    """
    A handler class which sends log strings to a wx object
    """
    def __init__(self, wxDest=None):
        """
        Initialize the handler
        @param wxDest: the destination object to post the event to 
        @type wxDest: wx.Window
        """
        logging.Handler.__init__(self)
        self.wxDest = wxDest
        self.level = logging.DEBUG

    def flush(self):
        """
        does nothing for this handler
        """


    def emit(self, record):
        """
        Emit a record.

        """
        try:
            msg = self.format(record)
            evt = wxLogEvent(message=msg,levelname=record.levelname)            
            wx.PostEvent(self.wxDest,evt)
        except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
            raise
        except:
            self.handleError(record)
```

Then in your control

```
self.Bind(EVT_WX_LOG_EVENT, self.onLogEvent)

def onLogEvent(self,event):
    '''
    Add event.message to text window
    '''
    msg = event.message.strip("\r")+"\n"
    self.logwindow.AppendText(msg) # or whatevery
    event.Skip()
```

Comment: @Vinjay Sajip: your answer is not thread safe if events are logged outside of wx main loop. It is safer to use wx events to process data from external threads.

Comment: No doubt you're right, but my answer just points to the approach to be used rather than offering a fully battle-tested solution.

Comment: According to wxPython docs (currently 4.2.0) at https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.functions.html#wx.CallAfter, `CallAfter` is ok to make a GUI call from another thread. @RobinDunn confirms that in https://stackoverflow.com/a/61377484/5642219. Edit to add link to the documentation: https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.functions.html#wx.CallAfter

Comment: And Mouse-vs-Python says that CallAfter is also trehad-safe. Whilst also providing a methodology to work with events: https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/05/22/wxpython-and-threads/ (already in May 2010)

Answer (score 5):

Here's a simple working example:

```
import logging
import random
import sys
import wx

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class WxTextCtrlHandler(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(self, ctrl):
        logging.Handler.__init__(self)
        self.ctrl = ctrl

    def emit(self, record):
        s = self.format(record) + '\n'
        wx.CallAfter(self.ctrl.WriteText, s)

LEVELS = [
    logging.DEBUG,
    logging.INFO,
    logging.WARNING,
    logging.ERROR,
    logging.CRITICAL
]

class Frame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        TITLE = "wxPython Logging To A Control"
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, TITLE)

        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        log = wx.TextCtrl(panel, wx.ID_ANY, size=(300,100),
                          style = wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_READONLY|wx.HSCROLL)
        btn = wx.Button(panel, wx.ID_ANY, 'Log something!')
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onButton, btn)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(log, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        sizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        handler = WxTextCtrlHandler(log)
        logger.addHandler(handler)
        FORMAT = "%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s"
        handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(FORMAT))
        logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    def onButton(self, event):
        logger.log(random.choice(LEVELS), "More? click again!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = Frame().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of running script]

**Update:** As iondiode points out, this simple script may have problems if there are multiple threads in your app, all logging via such a handler; ideally only a UI thread should update the UI. You can use the suggested approach of logging the event by using a custom event, as per his answer.

Comment: is the line logging.Handler.__init__(self) correct? Is it right to pass self inside __init__ ?

Answer (score 3):

You will need to create a custom `logging.Handler` and add it to your `logging.Logger`.

From the documentation:

> `Handler` objects are responsible for
>   dispatching the appropriate log
>   messages (based on the log messages’
>   severity) to the handler’s specified
>   destination. Logger objects can add
>   zero or more handler objects to
>   themselves with an addHandler()
>   method. As an example scenario, an
>   application may want to send all log
>   messages to a log file, all log
>   messages of error or higher to stdout,
>   and all messages of critical to an
>   email address. This scenario requires
>   three individual handlers where each
>   handler is responsible for sending
>   messages of a specific severity to a
>   specific location.

See http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#handler-objects for the `Handler` API.

In particular, it is the `Handler.emit(record)` method that you can implement to specify the destination of the output.  Presumably, you would implement this to call `TextCtrl.AppendText`.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer**

A general solution for custom log routing might look something like this:

```py
import logging

class CustomLogHandler(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(self, handler: "function"):
        logging.Handler.__init__(self)
        self.handler = handler
    def emit(self, record)
        record = self.format(record)
        self.handler(record)
```

**Exmaple**

This custom handler would take in a function that would be called with the log message every time a logger using this handler logs a message. This means you can do something like this

```py
import logging

def myLogHandler(self, logMSG):
    print(logMSG)

logObj = logging.getLogger(name) # Name of your logger here (or root)
myCustHandler = CustomLogHandler(myLogHandler)
logObj.addHandler(myCustHandler)
```

`myLogHandler` would be called every time you log a message with `logObj`. As I wrote it, this would just print the log message to the console.

In that function, you could set up a way to route that log message to your GUI and get the desired output.

**Why does this not answer the question directly about wxPython?**

I wanted to provide a general solution that was framework-agnostic.

The handler class I wrote could still be used if you switched from wxPython to PyQt or Tkinter or any other framework/library. All that would have to change is the handler function. That makes this code much more reusable.

**Other Relevant Topics**

For anyone reading this solution: If you are not sure why this code is more reusable research some topics like *Dependency Injection* and *SOLID Design Principles* if you are unfamiliar with them. After reading a bit about those, the motivation for this particular design might become clearer.