# How to write custom python logging handler?

Tags: python, logging, console, python-logging

How to write custom console log function to output only on the console window log messages on a single line (not append) until the first regular log record.

```
progress = ProgressConsoleHandler()
console  = logging.StreamHandler()  

logger = logging.getLogger('test')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG) 
logger.addHandler(console)  
logger.addHandler(progress)

logger.info('test1')
for i in range(3):
    logger.progress('remaining %d seconds' % i)
    time.sleep(1)   
logger.info('test2')
```

So that the console output is only three lines:

```
INFO: test1
remaining 0 seconds... 
INFO: test2
```

Any suggestions on the best way on how to implement this?

Comment: Where is `log` defined? ... aside from the `log` in `math`...

Comment: Most of these should help: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+logging+handler

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirect logging output using custom logging handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819791/redirect-logging-output-using-custom-logging-handler)

Answer (score 68):

```
import logging
class ProgressConsoleHandler(logging.StreamHandler):
    """
    A handler class which allows the cursor to stay on
    one line for selected messages
    """
    on_same_line = False
    def emit(self, record):
        try:
            msg = self.format(record)
            stream = self.stream
            same_line = hasattr(record, 'same_line')
            if self.on_same_line and not same_line:
                stream.write(self.terminator)
            stream.write(msg)
            if same_line:
                stream.write('... ')
                self.on_same_line = True
            else:
                stream.write(self.terminator)
                self.on_same_line = False
            self.flush()
        except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
            raise
        except:
            self.handleError(record)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import time
    progress = ProgressConsoleHandler()
    console  = logging.StreamHandler()  

    logger = logging.getLogger('test')
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG) 
    logger.addHandler(progress)

    logger.info('test1')
    for i in range(3):
        logger.info('remaining %d seconds', i, extra={'same_line':True})
        time.sleep(1)   
    logger.info('test2')
```

Notice that only one handler is being registered, and the `extra` keyword argument to let the handler know it should stay on one line.  There is more logic in the `emit()` method to handle changes between messages that should stay on one line and messages that need to have their own line.

Comment: FYI for those coming across this: The 'terminator' attribute is only available in Python >= 3.2, see https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2010-October/590223.html

Comment: ^ yes @pat, but you can make this work in both 2.7/3.7 with the following:

`if not hasattr(self, 'terminator'):` (new line) `self.terminator = '\n'`

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer 1**

I have not thoroughly tested this solution, but it seems to work for basic logging functionality. Also, the way of implementing it is definitely not best practice. For these reasons, I don't recommend using this solution in production... at least without further testing

**Disclaimer 2**

Part of the reason this approach is not recommended/not best practice is because you can very easily accidentally override a method of the `logging.Logger` class in your wrapper class. If this happens, it can lead to strange, hard to explain bugs.

If using this approach, take care to check that any attribute/method names you plan to use in your own custom methods/attributes do not already exist in the `logging.Logger` class.

Refer to the documentation for the `logging` module for more information

Without further ado: The answer

**Answer**

I created a base class for custom loggers as such:

```py
import logging

class CustomLoggerBC():
    def __init__(self, name:str):
         self._logger = logging.getLogger(name)
         newdict = {k: getattr(self._logger, k) for k in dir(self._logger) if k not in dir(self)}
         self.__dict__.update(newdict)
```

You then can write your own custom logger that inherits from the base class `CustomLoggerBC` as such:

```py
class MyCustomLogger(CustomLoggerBC):
    def __init__(name:str, ...rest of your arguments here):
        super().__init__(name)
        ... rest of your custom constructor here
```

In your class constructor or any method in your class you can make any desired changes you want or would normally make to the `logging.Logger` instance stored in `self._logger` such as adding a handler or setting the log level:

```py
class MyCustomLogger(CustomLoggerBC):
    def __init__(name:str, ...rest of your arguments here):
        super().__init__(name)
        ... Define your handler here
        self._logger.addHandler(self._customHandler)
        self._logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        ... rest of your custom constructor here
```

**Examples**

Code like this:

```py
cl = MyCustomLogger("MyCustomLogger")
cl.info("This is a test")
cl.info("This is also a test")
```

Could easily produce something like this

> [  INFO  ] [05/19/2022 10:03:45] This is a test
>
> [  INFO  ] [05/19/2022 10:03:45] This is also a test

Additionally, you can even override the methods of the `logging.Logger` class (*although I don't recommend it*)

```py
class MyCustomLogger(CustomLoggerBC):
    def __init__(name:str, ...rest of your arguments here):
        super().__init__(name)
        ... rest of your custom constructor here
    def info(self, msg):
        print("My custom implementation of logging.Logger's info method!")
```

Code like this:

```py
cl = MyCustomLogger("MyCustomLogger")
cl.info("This is a test")
cl.info("This is also a test")
```

Now instead produces something like this

> My custom implementation of logging.Logger's info method!
>
> My custom implementation of logging.Logger's info method!

**Why Would You Want to Do This?**

You can preconfigure your loggers ahead of time. For instance, if you know the logger for part A of your application will have a certain format, a certain handler, and a certain level. It is much easier to do something like this in part A

```py
myPartALogger = PartACustomLogger()
```

instead of doing all the initializing work for the logger in part A.

It also makes loggers more reusable
if part A and part B need separate loggers but would have the same configuration (say for example same level and formatter but a different handle) you can create two instances of your PartACustomLogger for each part with different names and pass different handlers to each instance.

**Why it Works**

Essentially you are wrapping the `logging.Logger` class with `MyCustomLogger`. The base class `CustomLoggerBC` updates the subclass’s implementation instance dictionary with all the methods and attributes of the `logging.Logger` class so that the implementation essentially functions as the `logging.Logger` object.
Any attribute/method requests to your custom logger class `MyCustomLogger` appear to be forwarded to the `logging.Logger` instance to be resolved by the `logging.Logger` instance, but in reality your own class is resolving the requests. This makes so that it seems you are subclassing the `logging.Logger` class but in reality you aren’t.

Answer (score 0):

This is an addition to:
[Customizing Handlers](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#customizing-handlers-with-dictconfig) if you decide to use a json or yaml file to store your logging configuration (recommended).
If you do this you can customize the handlers without subclassing, and it will look way clearer.
I'll add here an example of my own, which along with the example in the Python Docu could be enough to cover most cases:

Consider that you may want to set a custom log level to a handler, but the handlers in the standard library don’t offer built-in support. You can customize handler creation using a plain function such as:

```
import logging, logging.config

def your_handler_creator_function(stream=None): 
#The reason for this argument is that it's the one the __init__ method in the "logging.StreamHandler" class receives
    handler = logging.StreamHandler(stream) #The type of handler I want to use
    handler.setLevel(MY_CUSTOM_LEVEL_PREVIOUSLY_DEFINED)
    return handler

LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': False,
'formatters': {
    'default': {
        'format': '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s %(message)s'
    },
},
'handlers': {
    "name_of_your_handler": {
        "()": "path.to.your.your_handler_creator_function",
        # This value "stream" is the one that will be passed to the function
        "stream": "ext://sys.stdout",
        # The handler will get the values below automatically
        "formatter": "default",
        "filters": [
            "filter_name"
        ]
    },
},
'root': {
    'handlers': ['file'],
    'level': 'DEBUG',
},
}

logging.config.dictConfig(LOGGING)
logger = logging.getLogger('mylogger')
logger.debug('A debug message')
```