# Creating a custom slack log handler doesn't work

Tags: python, logging, event-handling, slack

I want to create a custom python logging `Handler` to send messages via slack.

I found this [package](https://github.com/mathiasose/slacker_log_handler) however its no longer being updated so i created a very bare bone version of it. however it doesnt seem to work, I added a `print` call for debugging purposes and `emit` is not being evoked.

```
import logging
# import slacker

class SlackerLogHandler(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(self, api_key, channel):
        super().__init__()
        self.channel = channel
        # self.slacker = slacker.Slacker(api_key)

    def emit(self, record):
        message = self.format(record)
        print('works')
        # self.slacker.chat.post_message(text=message, channel=self.channel)

slack_handler = SlackerLogHandler('token', 'channel')
slack_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
slack_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

logger = logging.getLogger('my_app')
logger.addHandler(slack_handler)
logger.info('info_try')  # 'works' is not printed and no slack message is sent
```

---

I saw this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118059/how-to-write-custom-python-logging-handler) and tried to also inherit from `StreamHandler` but to no avail.

I think I am missing something very basic.

edited to remove slack logic for ease of reproduction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some additional searching I found out that the logging level that is set for the handler is separate from the level that is set for the logger.

meaning, that adding:

```
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

fixes the problem.

Comment: I am trying to get something similar done. Can you provide a link to your repo or add back the slack logic/rest of the stuff :)

Comment: @saharudra you can see the edit history, but the slack logic is still there just commented out